# Showing multiple lines textarea value in an div elemtent using js

Tags: javascript, html

I have a text area, a button and a div

```
<textarea type="text" id="mytext"></textarea>
<button onclick="test()">Click Me</button>
<div id="here"></div>
```

Here is the script

```
<script>
    function test() {
        var b = document.getElementById('mytext').value;
        document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = b;
    }
</script>
```

I wrote following text in text area:

```
Hello All
Good Morning
```

But when i pressed Click Me, it gives following text in div element:

```
Hello All Good Morning
```

How to show multiple lines as in textarea?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use `replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');` to replace all line breaks in a string with `<br />` tag  **like:**

```js
function test() {
        var b = document.getElementById('mytext').value;
        b = b.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');
        document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = b;
    }
```

```html
<textarea type="text" id="mytext"></textarea>
<button onclick="test()">Click Me</button>
<div id="here"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace the new line with br tag.

Example Code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<textarea type="text" id="mytext"></textarea>
<button onclick="test()">Click Me</button>
<div id="here"></div>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test() {
        var b = document.getElementById('mytext').value;
        b = b.replace(/\r|\n/,"<br>");
        document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = b;
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace new line characters with `<br>` tag.

```js
function test() {
  var b = document.getElementById('mytext').value;
  document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = b.replace(/\n\r?/g, '<br>');
}
```

```html
<textarea type="text" id="mytext"></textarea>
<button onclick="test()">Click Me</button>
<div id="here"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixing text area and div size with br replace is giving effective result.

```js
function test() {
  var b = document.getElementById('mytext').value;
  document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = b.replace(/\n\r?/g, '<br>');
}
```

```css
#here {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

#mytext {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<textarea type="text" id="mytext"></textarea>
<button onclick="test()">Click Me</button>
<div id="here"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

> https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

**Example**
Split a string into an array of substrings:

```
var str = "How are you doing today?";
var res = str.split(" ");
//The result of res will be an array with the values:
```

**Output:** How,are,you,doing,today?

Comment: sorry, my question didnt show new line. I edited the question abover now. Please check